# add class dynamically in web components from JavaScript using classList

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

How to add dynamic styles to the shadow DOM

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="import" href="nav-component.html">
</head>
<body>
    <app-nav></app-nav>
</body>
</html>
```

---

nav-component.html

```
<template>
  <style>
    .btn {
        background-color: green;
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }
  </style>
    <button onclick="getstyles()">ENTER</button>
</template>
<script src="nav-component.js"></script>
```

---

nav-component.js

```
let template = document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector('template');
let clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
let proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

proto.createdCallback = function () {
    let root = this.createShadowRoot();
    root.appendChild(clone);
}
document.registerElement('app-nav', {
    prototype: proto
});

function getstyles() {
    console.log('it works');
    document.querySelector('button').classList.add('btn');
    // document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector('button').classList.add('btn');
}
```

have to add **btn** class to **button element** , so that its styles added to button element

got error 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null**

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/cMAX4YfQdcjP9nh66jVN?p=preview)

Comment: can't you not use Jquery? $('#buttonId').addClass('btnClass')

Comment: FYI, `document.registerElement` is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `document.registerElement` is deprecated so I answered class based custom element solution here...

The solution is to get the document from `document.currentScript.ownerDocument`

```
class AppNavElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()

        // import from ownerDocument
        const importDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
        let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        const template = importDoc.querySelector('#template');
        const instance = template.content.cloneNode(true);
        shadowRoot.appendChild(instance);

        // Event Listener
        this.addEventListener('click', e => this.changeStyle());
    }

    changeStyle() {
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('button').classList.add('btn')
    }
}

customElements.define('app-nav', AppNavElement)
```

Update:

To listen the button element only use the `connectedCallback` thanks @bhv

```
connectedCallback() { 
    let btn = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('button') 
    // Event Listener 
    btn.addEventListener('click', e => this.changeStyle()); 
}
```

Comment: thanks @Raja -  can you test the same app by adding event in html `<button onclick="changeStyle()">ENTER</button>`

Comment: @bhv there is way in React or other framework. But I don't know about Custom Elements. Sorry...

Comment: here the problem is , we are not selecting button element .. `this.addEventListener` - select whole template ..

Comment: can you mention how to add event to button element from app-nav ( a template may have multiple elements, how to select button element from that ) - sorry to ask you more questions :)

Comment: `connectedCallback` have to use to select element from shadowroot  `connectedCallback() {
        let btn = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('button')
        // Event Listener
        btn.addEventListener('click', e => this.changeStyle());
    }`

Comment: yes it worked, `connectedCallback` have to use , can you update the code in answer

Comment: Wow it's great now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply get the `<button>` element from the `event.target` property :

```
function changeStyle() {
    console.log('it works');
    event.target.classList.add('btn');
}

...

<button onclick="changeStyle()">ENTER</button>
```